# form.is_valid() returns False and the login() function doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to login a user who was previously registered in a database, but the `form.is_valid()` returns False and the `login()` function doesn't work. I extended the User class with a `Client` class that is inheriting from `User`, and I think this is what is causing the issue, because I tried almost the same code before, but without the extended `User` class, and it worked perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Client(User):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
```

My forms.py:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 
class Auth(forms.ModelForm):   
   class Meta:
      model = User  #I tried here both User and Client and returns the same result (form isn't valid)
    fields = [
        'username',
        'password',
    ]
    labels = {
        'username': '',
        'password': '',
    }
    widgets = {
        'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Usuario', 'style':'margin-bottom:15px'}),
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Contraseña'}),
    }
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Cart
from .forms import Auth
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout    

def main(request):
     productos = Cart.objects.all()
     users=User.objects.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.warning(request,'Ya existe un usuario autenticado')
        return redirect('main')

    else:
        form = Auth(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user=form['username'].value()
            password=form['password'].value()
            authuser=authenticate(request,username=user,password=password)

            if authuser is not None:
                login(request, authuser)
                messages.success(request, 'Bienvenido')
                return redirect('main')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Credenciales no válidas')
                return redirect('main')

else:
    form = Auth()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"form": form, 'productos':productos,'users':users})
```

The `authenticate()` function returns the right value, so the `authuser` variable is not `None`. But I don't know why the `login()` function does nothing, even when I try to login the user from the admin interface.

Comment: Check out the errors by accessing `form.errors`

Answer (score 0):

First you shouldn't use inherit of the Django base User: 
`from django.contrib.auth.models import User` 
If you whant extand the django user classe, use this one:  
`from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser`  
Here is the link from the django docs: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/)

Here is an other link if find useful: [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#proxy)